# Python - pip won't be recognized even after adding it to the PATH system variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, environment-variables, pip

I update python to the newer version and I edited the PATH system variables accordingly. I couldn't use pip now as it is not recognized by the system anymore. I added the PATH as: C:\Python34\Scripts. I also used `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"`. But the `echo %PATH%` shows the following with `/pip` appended.

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you just add the directory in the path? Or you have pip.exe under pip

Comment: You do not need to include \Scripts\Pip, rather \Scripts\ would do

Comment: You did restart cmd prompt right? Also, going into system preferences and editing the PATH there will solve your problem (not very pretty though)

Comment: Ah... Damn! Yeah! Thanks... I was meddling with another command window! My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the command prompt fixed everything.